# XAML photo effects

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, effects

So it is needed to be sayd im completely new to WPF and XAML.
I got as a project to make a program that when you insert a picture you must add effects some to it.I dont really know much about WPF so I need your help.
I need 1 effect from you guys so i can have an example to make the other ones.

Comment: Instead of `Button.Effect`, Did you try `Image.Effect`? Try something obvious like that yourself first, come back if you have issues.

Comment: I found code for 3 effects that is good enough for my task but i dont know how to make in XAML that when the button is pressed to make the changes to the image, like its this-> on WPF.Help me pls

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your image in memory or on a page like so:

```
<Image Source="sourceimage.png" Name="myImage">
    <Image.Effect>
        <BlurEffect />
    </Image.Effect>
</Image>
```

Next you'll need the following function to save a visual into a bitmap (there are easier/simpler ways to do this but this function handles certain fringe cases better):

```
    private static BitmapSource CaptureScreen(Visual target, double dpiX, double dpiY)
    {
        if (target == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        Rect bounds = VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(target);
        RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)(bounds.Width * dpiX / 96.0),
                                                        (int)(bounds.Height * dpiY / 96.0),
                                                        dpiX,
                                                        dpiY,
                                                        PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        DrawingVisual dv = new DrawingVisual();
        using (DrawingContext ctx = dv.RenderOpen())
        {
            VisualBrush vb = new VisualBrush(target);
            ctx.DrawRectangle(vb, null, new Rect(new Point(), bounds.Size));
        }
        rtb.Render(dv);
        return rtb;
    }
```

Finally save it to a file using something like a PNG encoder:

```
var bitmap = CaptureScreen(this.myImage, 96, 96);
PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap));
using (var s = File.Create(@"filename.png"))
    encoder.Save(s);
```

Keep in mind though that if you're saving an image that has been added to an on-screen window then you'll have to do all this in the Loaded handler or something, if you try and do it before all the framework elements have been initialized then your image will be blank.

Now that I've said all this let me just say I think it's a reall, REALLY bad idea to use WPF for doing things like this. WPF shader effects are notoriously flakey, as are many of the hardware drivers it relies on, and you'd be much better using a proper image processing library.

Comment: Thank you for your answer i have just one more question.How do i make so that the blur effect is on the photo when i press the button.

Comment: Just do something like "this.myImage.Effect = new BlurEffect();" in your view code.

Comment: i understood what you sayd but its good enough for a very small project. the only problem i faced was with the PNG encoder that did not detect File.Create and sayd File does not exist in the current context.I put that code for PNG encoder under a button as i want it to save only when i press the save button.Can you help me with that please?

Comment: i got rid of the error after doing this using (var s = System.IO.File.Create(@"filename.png"))
                encoder.Save(s);

Comment: but i still have no idea where the file is salved or if it is saved because i get no errors

Comment: so i found out this does work and save but it does only save a portion of the image

Comment: it does save all of it nevermind thanks for your help

Comment: Glad to hear it works for you (and sorry for my delayed response...I haven't logged on for a couple of days).

Comment: i got just one more problem.And no problem man im glad i found out the answer.

Comment: Im trying to add a outer glow effect and nothing happends.Blur and drop shadow works perfectly but Outer Glow does not.Ill add the code on edit.

Comment: so i found out there is a problem with BITMAP Effect and EFFECT and for that reason since 4.0 there is issue with outer glow and some BitmapEffects so i just created my own outer glow from Drop Shadow.Thank you for all your help.